# how to show a jquery datepicker on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show a datepicker only on button click

```
<input type="button" id=day value="day" />
$("#day").datepicker();
```

the above line fills the button text with the selected date

I have also tried with below code but nothing happens

```
$("#day").click(function() {
    $("#hiddenField").datepicker('show');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with the built-in `showOn` function:

```
$( "#hiddenField" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "day"
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uv8V4/

Reference: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a button as a trigger to the jQuery DatePicker as mentioned below,

```
<script type="text/javascript>"
  $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date"
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Click on the following link for a working fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/rtt25a1m/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
$("#hiddenField").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Choose Date',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    constrainInput: true
});
```

in `$(document).ready(function(){});` function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try following :

```
$("#day").click(function() {
        $("#hiddenField").datepicker("show");
    });
```

single quotes doesn't work.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize datepicker for your input field first

```
$('#input_filed').datepicker();
```

Then you need add trigger for button

```
$('#button').click(function() {
      $('#input_filed').datepicker('show');
});
```