# how can i get the datepicker in html input type='date' on clicking the input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

What should I do to get the Date-Picker on clicking the input field in html

> input type='date'

.

Comment: Which date-picker are you using? There are several. Also please provide a little more code as well, to help us help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-datepicker?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: first result on google ...

Comment: @rrd just the basic input type=date ..and also the code must be in javascript

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for ? Your code is only missing the opening and closing symbols. More info on input of type date can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp).

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: the datepicker opens only on clicking the far right..but i want it to open just by clicking anywhere on the input

Comment: Your only option is to use jQuery or Bootstrap datepickers then. There are plenty of examples available here to see how to do that, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239457/how-to-show-a-jquery-datepicker-on-button-click